# How to use OR operator properly in Golang

Tags: go

How can i do this simplified in Golang

```
var planningDate string
  date, ok := data["planningDate"]
  if !ok {
    planningDate = util.TimeStamp()
  } else {
    planningDate = date
  }
```

Thanx

Comment: You're doing a bitwise "or" on two timestamps? Is that supposed to be `||` rather than `|`? What exactly is that line of JavaScript supposed to do?

Comment: if data.planningDate is undefined it will uses the util.TimeStamp() as its value.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript very well. A quick Google search indicated that `|` is the bitwise "or" operator, and `||` is logical "or". If you say it works as you describe in this context, I'll take your word for it -- but I suggest you update your question, since a lot of people who know Golang are also likely not to know JavaScript very well. Your question might be clearer without referring to JavaScript at all.

Comment: Why are you editing out relevant parts of your question? Now all the comments make no more sense.

Comment: @JensG: Probably because I suggested that the edited parts were confusing. At least I found them so.

Comment: I just tried an experiment. Your (now deleted but still visible in the edit history) JavaScript snippet suggests that this: `var x = undefined; var y = x | "foo"; print(y);` should print `foo`; when I try it, it prints `0`. When I replace the `|` by `||`, it prints `foo`. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think that you could put the JavaScript snippet back into the question if you (a) change the `|` to `||` and (b) include a brief explanation of what it does. Or does the `|` mean something other than bitwise "or"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this in a single line, as there is no [ternary operator](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form) in Go. You cannot use `|` either as operands are not numbers. However, here is a solution in three lines (assuming `date` was just a temporary variable):

```
planningDate, ok := data["planningDate"]
if !ok {
    planningDate = util.TimeStamp()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
func T(exp bool, a, b interface{}) interface{} {
    if exp {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

and use it whenever you want, like a ternary-operator:

```
planningDate = T((ok), date, util.TimeStamp())
```